# Last SQLSTATE - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

is there anyway that I can get the last SQLSTATE generated by any exception/command execute, something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SQL_STATE()
RETURNS CHAR(5)
AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN (SELECT pg_last_error.SQLSTATE);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this information is transient.

PostgreSQL sends the SQLSTATE in the server's response to a query. If you need to keep that, you have to do so in the client code.

Since your question contains PL/pgSQL code, I'll describe how that works there:
The SQLSTATE is only accessible in the `EXCEPTION` handler of a PL/pgSQL block, where it can be accessed through the variable `SQLSTATE`. Again, you'd have to retain this information yourself if you need it later.